# why does heroku change the order of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, hash

for the life of me i could not figure this out.

if i have this in my local dev/production:

fields = { :name => { ...}, :description => { ...}, :amount => { .... } }

its fine i loop through my hashes and print the fields name just like how i declared it.

In heroku, the sequence is different in printed order?? I have complete no idea why and i can't get a clue why heroku is printing them in different order.

does that make sense?

Edit: OMG its driving me nuts. I actually do this in my templat, sorting my variable but For some reaaaaaly weird reason, its still coming out in a manner heroku only understands.

```
- @form_columns = @form_columns.sort_by do |i| 
  - if i[1][:rank].nil?
    - i[1][:rank] = rank
  - i[1][:rank]  
  - rank = rank + 1
```

This is how i loop by the way:

- @form_columns.each do |column_name|

Please understand that there is no issue in my local production/dev server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you for some reason have to use Ruby 1.8 then you can get an ordered hash by using `OrderedHash` in Rails `ActiveSupport`.

To see what [stack](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack) you are using on Heroku:

```
heroku stack
```

and to migrate to 1.9.2:

```
heroku stack:migrate bamboo-mri-1.9.2
```

Comment: this is the most beautiful answer thanks. just migrate to 1.9.2 and done.

Answer (score 2):

The order of keys within a Hash is not guaranteed to equal the order in which were inserted, in Ruby 1.8

That behaviour is different in Ruby 1.9, where the order is preserved.

http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/

Are you using ruby 1.8?

Comment: i believe im using 1.9:David-Angs-MacBook-Air:eweds mickeyren$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-darwin10.5.0]

Comment: That's on your machine on Heroku you could still be on 1.8.

Comment: okay, i sort it regardless. understood in heroku maybe 1.8. thanks for the help guys.